# Application of pascal paradox

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

My points of interests is at point A and B. I want to investigate how much pressure is acting on this two points. (Ignore Atmospheric pressure and work in gage pressure).

Since the oil will flow up into the manometer like tube, is there any way to evaluate the pressure at those points ? Because I do not lie how is it done or whether it is even possible by calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Not without knowing the position of the menisci in the u-tube. Even if the LHS oil bath is not there you can have different pressures at B for  different hights of the oil column in the RHS part of the tube. It depends on how much (mass) air ther is in the sealed can.

Comment: Could you perhaps add a few more details to this answer?